# Collecting paginated data of unknown size using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm querying a REST-API to get all groups. Those groups come in batches of 50. I would like to collect all of them before continuing to process them.

Up until now I relied on callbacks but I'd like to use promises to chain the retrieval of all groups and then process the result-array further.

I just don't quite get how to replace the recursive functional call using promises.

**How would I use A+ promises to escape the callback hell I create with this code?**

```
function addToGroups() {
   var results = []

   collectGroups(0)

   function collectGroups(offset){
     //async API call
     sc.get('/tracks/'+ CURRENT_TRACK_ID +'/groups?limit=50&offset=' + offset , OAUTH_TOKEN, function(error, data){

       if (data.length > 0){
         results.push(data)
         // keep requesting new groups
         collectGroups(offset + 50)
       }
       // finished
       else {
         //finish promise
       }
     })
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *standard* promises, wrap all of your existing code as shown here:

```
function addToGroups() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ...  // your code, mostly as above
    });
}
```

Within your code, call `resolve(data)` when you're finished, or `reject()` if for some reason the chain of calls fails.

To make the whole thing more "promise like", first make a function `collectGroups` return a promise:

```
function promiseGet(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sc.get(url, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
// NB: promisify-node can do the above for you

function collectGroups(offset, stride) {
    return promiseGet('/tracks/'+ CURRENT_TRACK_ID +'/groups?limit=' + stride + '&offset=' + offset , OAUTH_TOKEN);
}
```

and then use this Promise in your code:

```
function addToGroups() {
    var results = [], stride = 50;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        (function loop(offset) {
            collectGroups(offset, stride).then(function(data) {
                if (data.length) {
                    results.push(data);
                    loop(offset + stride);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            }).catch(reject);
        )(0);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. This there also a more "promise"-style way of collecting the groups themself?

Comment: That depends on whether `sc.get` returns a promise or not.  If it doesn't, stick with this.

Comment: @Alnitak, if it does, we have a nicer solution? May be you can write one more example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This could work. I am using https://github.com/kriskowal/q promises.

```
  var Q = require('q');

  function addToGroups() {
     var results = []
     //offsets hardcoded for example
     var a = [0, 51, 101];
     var promises = [], results;
     a.forEach(function(offset){
        promises.push(collectGroups(offset));
     })
     Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(){
        promises.forEach(function(promise, index){
          if(promise.state === 'fulfilled') {
            /* you can use results.concatenate if you know promise.value (data returned by the api)
               is an array */
            //you also could check offset.length > 0 (as per your code)
            results.concatenate(promise.value); 
            /*
              ... do your thing with results ...
            */
          }
          else {
            console.log('offset',index, 'failed', promise.reason);
          }
        });
     });
   }

  function collectGroups(offset){
    var def = Q.defer();
    //async API call
    sc.get('/tracks/'+ CURRENT_TRACK_ID +'/groups?limit=50&offset=' + offset , OAUTH_TOKEN, function(error, data){
      if(!err) {
        def.resolve(data);
      }
      else {
        def.reject(err);
      }
    });
    return def.promise;
  }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That looks _way_ more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Well, I was comparing to my answer, where a mere three lines of code are needed to add promises to the OP's code.

Comment: You only wrap addToGroups in a promise (by returning one). But I think @hedge is trying to parallelize API calls here. The call back hell as he says does not go away in your solution because it resides in collectGroups and not addToGroups. Let me know what you think ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's complete example, using [spex.sequence](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/code/sequence.md):

```
var spex = require("spex")(Promise);

function source(index) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        sc.get('/tracks/' + CURRENT_TRACK_ID + '/groups?limit=50&offset=' + index * 50, OAUTH_TOKEN, function (error, data) {
            resolve(data.length ? data : undefined);
        });
    });
}

spex.sequence(source, {track: true})
    .then(function (data) {
        // data = all the pages returned by the sequence;
    });
```

I don't think it can get simpler than this ;)